# Redirecting .htaccess for only / root of server and leave DIRs alone?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have multiple parked domains and using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

to redirect them to a default domain,but I also want to redirect any https traffic to http but not force other areas such as /server-status, administrator, phpmyadmin. Is that possible?

Can I achieve this without causing looping and pretty much keeping it were it isn't forcing 443/https or http/80 traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help Anubhava

I figured out the problem since I had time today to complete it. I'm still using my rule to forward parked domains to my default domain which is this below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

which works great and faster then the 301 rule.

I also have a extension that redirects all my traffic in the back-end to https but not forced. I also have the option to force other plugins and modules, etc for redirects if I need.

I managed to find the culprit!  The issue was cloudflare.com keeping my cache and redirecting my connections back as a loop to http and then https.

If you have CDN make sure you clear the cache or make sure https options are correct.

Problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another rule for `https` redirection with some exceptions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(server-status|phpmyadmin|administrator)
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(server-status|phpmyadmin|administrator)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: That gave me error message that http and https for www.domain.com was forbidden. It did let me into the phpmyadmin, administrator and server-status though.

Comment: Forbidden error cannot be caused by these 2 rules. Do you have other rules also in your .htaccess?

Comment: Your htaccess isn't showing my rules. Make sure these rules are placed `www` adding redirect rule.

Comment: Where is the best place I should place your code? I didn't use it or display it because I was getting loops. I do have sh404sef to installed but I did purge the url list but still looping. Please let me know where from the script I shared a link, thanks

Comment: As I suggested place these new rules just below your `www adding redirect rule`.

Comment: Show your latest .htaccess which is causing redirect loop. Then open Firebug and visit `http://www.domain.com` and tell me what redirects you see under `Net` tab.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS https://www.domain.com/
GET https://www.domain.com/ net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS www.linuxsecrets.com/:1
GET https://www.domain.com/ net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS www.linuxsecrets.com/:1
GET https://www.dimain.com/ net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qNVGLaGv   It seems to be redirecting to https but should only be redirecting to https for /administrator etc.

Comment: Ok, inserted the above and when I visit the https://www.domain.com/administrator is has the same loop but working for non-https which is a good start.

Comment: ok try updated code again and if you get redirect loop then check Firebug again.